# RX fluent subscribing to observables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have three observables:

```
var itemsManipulationStarted =
                Observable.FromEvent<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(Items, "ManipulationStarted");

var pageManipulationDelta = Observable.FromEvent<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(this, "ManipulationDelta");

var pageManipulationCompleted =
                Observable.FromEvent<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(this, "ManipulationCompleted");
```

They are always called in that sequense: itemsManipulationStarted -> pageManipulationDelta -> pageManipulationCompleted

After every call to any observable I need to make some actions:

```
itemsManipulationStarted.Subscribe(e => Items.IsHitTestVisible = false);

pageManipulationDelta.SkipUntil(itemsManipulationStarted)
                     .Subscribe(e => e.EventArgs.Complete());

pageManipulationCompleted.SkipUntil(pageManipulationDelta)
                         .Subscribe(e => Items.IsHitTestVisible = true);
```

Is it clear or is there another way to write some "fluent" subscribing?

Comment: To be clear.. do you rely on these events working in this order?

Comment: @DanPantry, yes

Answer (score 4):

If you're on C# 5.0, you can use `await` with `IObservable`s to write code like this:

```
await itemsManipulationStarted.FirstAsync();
Items.IsHitTestVisible = false;

var e = await pageManipulationDelta.FirstAsync();
e.EventArgs.Complete();

await pageManipulationCompleted.FirstAsync();
Items.IsHitTestVisible = true;
```

Though I'm not completely sure this will do what you want, because of timing.

Comment: Actually I'm under windows phone 7 :\ Thanks!

Comment: wow. Actually I can use `async\await`.
I'll try your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: If when I'm awaiting `xxx.FirstAsync()` and the `IObservable` becomes disposed, I would got an exception?

Comment: Well, yes. The observable becomes disposed so the element you are awaiting becomes unreachable.

It might be worth instead re-writing your code to not use `.FirstAsync()` (although you can do this) and instead utilize the various methods in Rx to combine sequences. All of this could be feasibly combined into a single sequence.

Answer (score 2):

As per your comment, it appears that you rely on events working in this order.
This seems like a bit of an anti-pattern to me to give the end-user the freedom to use all of these events, but rely on them working in the order that they do.

As a result, I would recommend removing the "ManipulationStarted" and "ManipulationCompleted" events. Instead, I would suggest something more along the lines of this:

```
pageManipulationDelta.Subscribe(e => e.EventArgs.Complete());
```

And then only fire this event - the "ManipulationDelta" event during the period of Manipulation being started or ended (whatever manipulation is). There is almost certainly a better way to approach your issue. There is no need for you to have these 3 observables 'flow' into each other. Instead, you should only expose *one* observable - let the event publisher decide on any security restrictions... such as state mutation, which is against the nature of Rx itself anyway.

Revised code:

```
var pageManipulationDelta = Observable.FromEvent<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(this, "ManipulationDelta");

....
// When we start manipulation
IsManipulationStarted = true;
ManipulationDelta(args);
IsManipulationStarted = false;
```

Although the fact there is the mutation of a boolean state variable confuses me - why is this necessary? To give a more indepth review of your code I will need to see the reason why you have approached it the way you have.

Note that this is not tested:

```
       var combinedObservable = Observable.Defer(() =>
            {
                var allowPublications = false;
                var subscription = startObservable.Select(_ => true)
                        .Merge(endObservable.Select(_ => false))
                        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                        .Subscribe(state => allowPublications = state);
                return Observable.Using(() => subscription, _ => deltaObservable.DoWhile(() => allowPublications));
            });
```

This is the simplest way I see of approaching your problem without exposing state. This allows you to completely encapsulate the state of your enabled/disabled delta publications. Replace `startObservable`, `endObservable` and `deltaObservable` as required. You may want to consider reducing the `Throttle`, but I figure it's pretty necessary since you are dealing with UI input to debounce your events.

You can expose `combinedObservable` and subscribe to that in place of your `ManipulationDeltaEvent` - the start/end capabilities will be handled automagically. You will need to add sequence repeating yourself.

Comment: Actually events are raised by my WP7 controls. The goal of my code is to block swipe gesture in the pivot control.

Comment: The goal of my code is to block a swipe gesture in the pivot control. 
The pivot (its name is Items in the code) is a child of page. To block swipe gesture I need to catch the `ManipulationStarted` event on Items and set `Items.IsHitTestVisible = false` to prevent handling swipe gesture.
After `Items`, the event bubbled to the parent control (it is page). In the `ManipulationDelta` of page I complete "manipulation" (to prevent animation). Next I set `Items.IsHitTestVisible = true` to allow up\down (scrolling) gesture.
So I'm not able to manually firing the events.
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: See my edit for a proposed solution.